How To Fill Holes In A Sculpture?
While sculpting a 3D character, i've accidentally created several holes in it. I am struggling to fill these holes. I've tried to remesh the object after adding clay, after using the grab tool, and after several other tools. But the problem still persists and the holes seem to get bigger. I've attached two images. The first image should show the two big holes in reference. The second image shows the extra tiny holes that have resulted as my attempts.
Is it true that sculpt mode might not be the best method to fill these? I've tried to move the vertices around in edit mode, but my technique doesn't seem to be working. Could you guys recommend anything? Thanks.



Use the Boolean modifier with some patches?

Ahh a patch being another mesh? This works. I just remeshed after and smoothed it over. Thank you.

Create a patch object and use a Boolean modifier to make it fill the hole.
